# UIActivityView and blocking

Tags: iphone, multithreading, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a section of code that uploads an image:

```
[activity startAnimating];
 [self uploadImage:img Session_id:appDelegate.sessionID PlaceID:place.placeID Comment:comment.text];
 [activity stopAnimating];
```

I am sure that activity is wired up correctly to a UIActivityViewIndicator, but it never shows. Inside the uploadImage function, I open a connection to the server and start the upload.  Does anyone have an example or possible explanation as to why the activity view would not display?

Comment: Did you add the activityView as a subview to an onscreen view? Or is it set in Interface Builder and assigned to an outlet? I suppose the latest, based on your post. As far as I know, UIActivityIndicator keeps spinning dven if the main thread is blocked. Maybe it's on a white background and the style of the activityIndicator set to white?

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing the upload on the main thread, then it's blocked and the UI cannot be updated.

I would suggest running it on a background thread.

Comment: have a look at the NSURLConnection and NSURLRequest (and its mutable friend). They will enable you to make connections and requests to web services asynchronously, leaving your main thread and UI unblocked.